# How to write your own python awaitable function that is not only calls other async functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have one blocking function:

```py
def blocking_function():
    doing.start_preparing()
    while not doing.is_ready():
        pass
    return doing.do()
```

I want to change it into an async function.

I've read some source code of asyncio, and I've found this two options:

```py
@types.coroutine
def yield_option() -> typing.Generator:
    doing.start_preparing()
    while not doing.is_ready():
        yield
    return doing.do()

def future_and_call_soon_option() -> asyncio.Future:
    doing.start_preparing()
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    future = loop.create_future()
    def inner():
        if not doing.is_ready():
            loop.call_soon(inner)
        else:
            future.set_result(doing.do())
    inner()
    return future
```

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(yield_option(), future_and_call_soon_option()) #runs concurently

asyncio.run(main())
```

Both of these options do work but which of them is better? Or is there any third option that is better to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
async def blocking_function():
    doing.start_preparing()
    while not doing.is_ready():
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return doing.do()
```

This will cooperate with other tasks.  It is simple and would probably be acceptable in practice if the blocking functions are fast enough.  But if the blocking functions take a significant amount of time it would be better to move them to another thread.